# Sending data to another page without a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I was informed that I can send data without a POST function. What I am trying to figure out is how I can get rid of the form around my table and send the data to my page called "edit-product".

In addition to the data, I want the user to be sent there as well, just like the form's action attribute would do.

As of now, I have it structured like this:

```
<?php
        $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT `id`,`first`,`last`,`product` FROM users");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="edit-product">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?>"</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['first'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['last'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['product'];?></td>
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" readonly>
                <input name="first" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['first'];?>">
                <input name="last" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['last'];?>">
                <input name="product" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['product'];?>">
                <td><input name="save" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                <td><div class="delete-class" name="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>
                <td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In my edit-product page, I receive the data like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Ajax would be the best (only?) way. Or did you mean using `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: How could I get the AJAX to take me to the edit-product page, though? I can figure out the AJAX for this, just not that part.

Comment: You want to send the user to the edit-product page?

Comment: U can use simple pop up in the same page for editing.

Comment: Yes, I want to send the user to the page to edit. I have more detailed info on that page.

Comment: Why do you want something exactly like a form which isn't a form?

Comment: @Quentin Because the way it sits now, the forms action isn't allowing me to do different things like delete records and stay on the same page - it takes me to the form's action page, but I needed the action to be there, so I could edit the record. I am going to be doing the deleting and what not with AJAX and I was told there is no need for a form with AJAX and that it could possibly be the reason why my current AJAX isn't working for my delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an edit button with anchor.

```
  <table>
     <tbody>
     <?php
        $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT `id`,`first`,`last`,`product` FROM users");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>       
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?>"</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['first'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['last'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['product'];?></td>                    
                <td><input name="save" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                <td><div class="delete-class" name="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>
                <td><a href="/edit-product?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&first=<?php echo $row['first'];?>&last=<?php echo $row['last'];?>&product=<?php echo $row['product'];?>">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>      
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And u can catch the url value from edit-prpduct page.
like

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$first = $_GET['first'];
$last = $_GET['last'];
$product = $_GET['product'];
```

Just try this without any form post.

Comment: What would it look like though??

Comment: <a href='/edit-product?id={id}&first={first}&last={last}&product={product}'>Edit</a>

Comment: U can use javascript for spliting and getting the values from the url